# Pure CSS dialog animation not working for dialog.close()

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make an animation for dialog, I tried this

```
.dialog[open] {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-animation: show-dialog 1s ease normal;
}
.dialog[close] {
    -webkit-animation: hide-dialog 1s ease normal;
}
.dialog::backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-animation: none;
}
.dialog[open]::backdrop {
    -webkit-animation: show-backdrop 0.5s ease 0.2s normal;
}
.dialog.[close]::backdrop {
    -webkit-animation: hide-backdrop 0.5s ease 0.2s normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes show-dialog {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hide-dialog{
    to {
        opacity: 0;
       transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes show-backdrop {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hide-backdrop{
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

For `.dialog[open]` the animations works correctly when I open the dialog, but when I want to close the dialog, it not working properly, I tried to use `.dialog[close]` but it not working, How to make an animation for dialog closing?'

Comment: What do you mean with "not working properly"? Is the animation not working at all. Tell us more about what is happing

Comment: The animation works when I open the dialog, but when I try to close it, animation not working

Comment: Can you show us some relevant HTML code? And if you use JS to change classes or something than would it be nice if you post that to.

Comment: Also, try to add `from{ /*css code*/ } to{ /*css code*/ }` instead of only `to{ /*css code*/ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[open]` refers to the HTML attribute `open` which appears on an `HTMLDialogElement` when it is opened. `close` is not a corresponding attribute. You will need to introduced your own close behavior through some combination of custom classes, attributes and events. Remember to take care of both the escape key and programmatic closing.